# How do I work with pointers in TASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, tasm

I am a beginner in assembly and I wanted to make a subroutine in assembly that receives a pointer to a location in memory that is ready to receive a string. Once it does so it will continually ask the user for a character, and save each character in the memory space pointed to by the pointer. Once the user types enter the subroutine stops asking for a character from the user, and it adds the dollar sign to the end of the string.

```
.MODEL SMALL

.DATA  

.CODE

START:

looping:
  mov ah, 06h
  int 21h
  cmp al, Dh
  je finish
  around here I am guessing I should save each character to the memory space
  pointed to by the pointer
  jmp looping

finish: around here I would add the dollar sign to the memory space pointed    
by the pointer

END START
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. So I have read some of your suggestions, thanks a lot for everything, but I was wondering could i do mov bx, address then push bx, and then pop bx lea cx, bx?

Comment: How is the pointer passed?

Comment: I was thinking of passing it through the stack

Comment: Lookup the `cdecl` calling convention and you'll see enough examples how to implement it in your program. Your assumptions about what you should have and where are accurate, you just need to implement them with a call to your procedure with pointer passed on stack.

Comment: Be sure to also pass the size of the memory area and don't let the user type too many characters.

Comment: Probably the best way for this function to accept its pointer arg is in `di` (or `ds:di` if you're not using a flat memory model).  Or whatever register `ah=6 / int 21h` uses as the pointer.  There's no point burdening yourself with a stack-args calling convention when you're writing a private helper function to be called from your own code.  You can also let the function clobber whichever registers you want.

Comment: And BTW `Dh` is a register name!  If you wanted a hex constant for ASCII CR, you should have written `0Dh`.  This is one of the nastiest cases where `0xDEADBEEF` syntax is better than `0DEADBEEFh` syntax, but I think TASM only supports the suffix notation.